# Generic Command Line SQL Program?

Tags: sql, shell, command-line

Is there any application/project that provides you with a command line SQL client that will work with multiple databases and/or provides a mechanism for writing your own drivers?

Put another way, I'm looking for something like the mysql command line client or SQL*Plus for Oracle, but that's database agnostic.

All platforms welcome, but extra points for OS X/*nix approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use something built on Perl and [DBI](http://dbi.perl.org/about/) like [DBI-Shell](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI-Shell/lib/DBI/Shell.pm)?

Answer (score 3):

Try sqlsharp from the [Mono subversion repository](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/tools/sqlsharp/). You can define new providers via a configuration file. They are loaded from .NET assemblies, so you can write your own provider if you want to, but Mono already has MS SQL and Oracle, plus postgres and MySQL provide their own .NET assemblies.

It works on any platform supported by Mono and MS.NET.

Comment: That looks pretty awesome.  Random related question: Is it a hard or easy thing to get the Mono run-time onto a system you don't have full access (i.e. root/sudo/Administrator) to?

Comment: Easy. You just need to either build it from sources (you'll need gcc, glib-2.0, make, autotools, libtool, pkg-config for windows, just VS + glib-2.0 and pkg-config) or install it in a folder where you have rights to write.

Comment: Unfortunately this link doesn't work any more and neither does the one at http://www.mono-project.com/Software. Does anybody know where is sqlsharp hosted now?

Comment: It's in the main mono repo; https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/sqlsharp

Answer (score 0):

a SQL client and front-end for multiple database is [Crunchyfrog](http://code.google.com/p/crunchyfrog/), which offers a [Native Database Shell](http://packages.python.org/crunchyfrog/nativeshell.html?highlight=command%20line).  Not sure if this meets your requriement

Comment: From that page, it looks like the native database shell is just running the existing executable from the database i.e. crunchyfrog isn't doing anything there...